# Within group move date to same date in prior year if certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust3'],
                   'date':[date(2017, 6, 15), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 6, 15), date(2019, 1, 20), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2020, 1, 10), date(2020, 6, 12), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 12, 10), date(2017, 1, 5), date(2018, 1, 15), date(2019, 2, 20)],
                   'c':[5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 5, 9]})

        a        date  c
0   cust1  2017-06-15  5
1   cust1  2017-12-15  5
2   cust1  2018-06-15  6
3   cust1  2019-01-20  6
4   cust1  2019-06-15  7
5   cust1  2020-01-10  7
6   cust1  2020-06-12  8
7   cust2  2017-12-15  4
8   cust2  2018-12-10  8
9   cust3  2017-01-05  6
10  cust3  2018-01-15  5
11  cust3  2019-02-20  9
```

a' = customer

'date' = date when customer paid

'c' = amount customer paid

I need to check if the customer paid as many times in each year then in the previous year but for customers which historically paid in December but in later years paid in January I would like to change the January date to a December date.

I tried the following:

```
year_end_month = [1, 12]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df_2 = df.loc[df['date'].dt.month.isin(year_end_month)].copy()
df_3 = pd.concat([df, df_2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
s=df_2.groupby('a').date.shift().dt.month
df_2['newDate']=np.where(s.eq(12) & df_2.date.dt.month.eq(1), df_2.date- 
pd.DateOffset(months=1), df_2.date)
df_4 = pd.concat([df_2, df_3])
df_4.newDate = df_4.newDate.fillna(df_4.date)
df_4.sort_values(by=['a', 'date'])
```

The problem with my approach is that it works the first time the payment date is moved from December to January but it doesn't work for subsequent years. so looking at cust1 first time she switchted payment from December to January was in December 2018 to January 2019 and my approach captures this. but my approach fails to move her 2019 payment which she made in January 2020 to December 2019. Any idea how this can be solved for?

my resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
        a       date  c    newDate
0   cust1 2017-06-15  5 2017-06-15
1   cust1 2017-12-15  5 2017-12-15
2   cust1 2018-06-15  6 2018-06-15
3   cust1 2019-01-20  6 **2018-12-20**
4   cust1 2019-06-15  7 2019-06-15
5   cust1 2020-01-10  7 **2019-12-10**
6   cust1 2020-06-12  8 2020-06-12
7   cust2 2017-12-15  4 2017-12-15
8   cust2 2018-12-10  8 2018-12-10
9   cust3 2017-01-05  6 2017-01-05
10  cust3 2018-01-15  5 2018-01-15
11  cust3 2019-02-20  9 2019-02-20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `ffill()` on the `shift()` month series

```
months = df.date.dt.month

s = months.eq(12).groupby(df['a']).shift()
df['date'] = np.where(months.eq(1) & s.where(s).groupby(df['a']).ffill(),
                      df['date'] - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset(),
                      df['date'])
```

Output:

```
        a       date  c
0   cust1 2017-06-15  5
1   cust1 2017-12-15  5
2   cust1 2018-06-15  6
3   cust1 2018-12-20  6
4   cust1 2019-06-15  7
5   cust1 2019-12-10  7
6   cust1 2020-06-12  8
7   cust2 2017-12-15  4
8   cust2 2018-12-10  8
9   cust3 2017-01-05  6
10  cust3 2018-01-15  5
11  cust3 2019-02-20  9
```